# shell script running from command line but not from another script

Tags: unix

I have a shell script A which is calling script B inside it with 2 parameters passing to B.

Now when I am executing A, the operations inside script B is not happening.

I did an RC after calling script B. It is returning 0. Si I am not sure whether script B is getting called or not.
I have given 777 permissions to script B
Also, when I am running the script B from command line, it is working fine.

What might be the issue ?

Please provide your inputs..

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome at SO. To help you it would be good to see your code. Only a guess: does your script need a terminal and A runs without?

Comment: Don't use 777 permissions; it means you don't care if your worst enemy does `echo 'rm -fr * 2>/dev/null &' >your.script`.